# Border area messed up with multiple SVG backgrounds

Tags: html, svg

I have a DIV image that I am stylizing as a button. For this, I am using two background images (SVG format) and a border (for debug purposes, the border is extra large). I want the background images to show beneath the border. Mockup CSS:

```
.element {
background: url(bg1.svg) no-repeat,
    url(bg2.svg) no-repeat;
background-clip:border-box, border-box;
-webkit-background-clip:border-box;
-moz-background-clip:border-box;
background-size: cover, cover;
border: 10px inset rgba(255, 255, 255, .20);
}
```

Note also that the element is a flex box, so it is dynamically resizing.

**The result:** Chrome, IE, Firefox, and Safari all display the background beneath part of the border, but not the whole thing.

Chrome and IE show the backgrounds only under the bottom panel of the border.

Chrome also has one or two px between the background and the border on the sides.

Any ideas on why this problem shows up or how to fix it?

**Edit:** The small gap between background and border in Chrome is generally not an issue when the images are in PNG format. The problem appears to be that the background doesn't scale enough. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix: background-size: cover seems to be based on the content size (without the border). Using a value greater than 100% fixes the problems for sufficiently large elements.

I also needed to add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the SVG script.